# Ubuntu 16.04 failed to start LSB: QEMU KVM module loading script

Tags: 16.04, startup, qemu

This is the error I get every time I start my system. I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 around a week ago.

Comment: @laugh - Thanks for the suggestion! I've reedited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATED
original response was incomplete

I had the same issue, you have to purge qemu-system-common. There is a left over config file. If you don't want to purge your qemu config files, you can let it sit around for a little longer. Next release in October will probably clear up this issue.

```
sudo apt-get purge qemu-system-common
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it was driving me Insane.

Also, I had the "Libvirt QEMU" user listed at the user log in screen in 16.04LTS. Just edited the /etc/passwd and removed the entry for that user.