# Fails to boot Kernels newer than 4.15: LSB: QEMU KVM module loading script

Tags: boot, kernel, kvm-virtualization

I currently cannot boot any kernels newer than 4.15 because my PC hangs on boot with the following message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3JY3.jpg

If I purge QEMU per the instructions found here: [Ubuntu 16.04 failed to start LSB: QEMU KVM module loading script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785639/ubuntu-16-04-failed-to-start-lsb-qemu-kvm-module-loading-script) I can boot just fine, however I need QEMU to run Polo File Manager.

How can I keep QEMU and boot a newer kernel?
My distro is KDE Neon.

Comment: This service should not do a lot that takes time, if you are interested in debugging you might check `systemd-analyze critical-chain` if it really is the one taking all the time after it booted eventually and add a `set -x` to `/usr/share/qemu/init/qemu-kvm-init` to have the steps in the log one by one probably pointing to the time consuming part.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary(?) fix! I disabled QEMU KVM from booting at start using the instructions found [here at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698993/disable-services-on-startup-in-ubuntu).
My command was

```
sudo systemctl disable qemu-kvm
```

and it WORKED.

I can boot now and Polo File Manager works just fine, although I haven't tested its KVM capabilities.